# Find and replace multiple attributes from img tag using PHP RegEx

Tags: php, regex

```
//Example of image
$image = '<img src="../img/image.jpeg" title="Title" alt="Alt"/>';
```

I have all this $patterns where i can take the value one at a time

```
// get the src for that image
$pattern_src = '/src="([^"]*)"/';

// get the title for that image
$pattern_title = '/title="([^"]*)"/';

// get the alt for that image
$pattern_alt = '/alt="([^"]*)"/';
```

How can i use **all** this $patterns with **preg_replace** like this:

```
preg_replace($pattern_src+$pattern_title+$pattern_alt,$1$2$3,$image);
```

Values

```
$1 => src value
$2 => title value
$3 => alt value;
```

Why i need it

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>
    $2 //Title value
    </figcaption>
    <img src="../web/img/$1"> //New src 
    <figcaption>
    $3 //Alt value
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: you want to just extract out `src`, `title` and `alt` and use it somewhere else..right?

Comment: Exactly, But I need to do at the same time

Answer (score 1):

*Obligatory comment about not using regex to parse HTML, and to use DOMDocument or something instead, blah blah blah. Anyway...*

Two options here.

First, if the attributes are always in the same order, you can simply separate your current rules with a `.*`:

`'/.*src="([^"]*)".*title="([^"]*)".*alt="([^"]*)"/'`

Second option, if they are not always in the same order, you can use positive lookaheads:

`'/(?=.*src="([^"]*)")(?=.*title="([^"]*)")(?=.*alt="([^"]*)")/'`

This will return `src`, `title` and `alt` as `$1`, `$2` and `$3` respectively, no matter what order they appear in the image tag. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/uI0uF9/2)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your example and the value of title and alt also src worked perfectly, but created many identical images ... You have idea why this happened? @rjdown

Comment: The second option @rjdown